# How to pass parameter from form post to view in Django - python ?

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm new to Django and I am stuck at how can I use my html request form to show in view :

**1. HTML form :**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <label for="your_name">Your name: </label>
    <input id="your_name" type="text" name="name" value="{{ name }}">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

**2. views/formout.py**

```
def pageform(request):

    name = request.POST.get('name', '')

    return render(request, 'en/public/index.html',{name : "name"})
```

**3. URL**

```
url (r'^form$', 'jtest.views.formout'),
```

**4. index.html**

```
<p>
    name : {{name}}
</p>
```

Comment: Welcome to Django! This framework is my passion. I'm not trying to be rude or anything like that, but you really need to work through the tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/ It will answer your question, and I'm sure many others that you'll have along the way.

Comment: @Brandon i did https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/

Comment: I'll post an answer for you.

Comment: If you've read that page you link to, why haven't you followed it? None of the code you have posted here has any relation to the examples on that page.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I got what example showed but I am trying to create my own and understand it myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to use an actual form class to sanitize and normalize any user-supplied values into their Python equivalent:

```
# forms.py

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Second, you need to leverage the form in your view:

```
# views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from your_app.forms import NameForm

def my_view(request):
    name_form = NameForm(request.POST or None, initial={'name': 'whatever'})

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if name_form.is_valid():
            # do something

    return render(request, 'name-form.html', {'name_form': name_form})
```

Lastly, your template needs to leverage the form:

```
# name-form.html

<form action="." method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    {{ name_form.name.label_tag }}
    {{ name_form.name }}
    {{ name_form.name.errors }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

By passing the initial value to the form class, Django will bind the value for you. If the form has errors, and `name` has a value, Django will re-bind the value submitted to that field from the `request.POST` dictionary.

Comment: Thank you @Brandon , I was so lost and it has been 3 weeks trying to understand this. I really appreciated it. This really help.